# git: How to wipe the slate clean when a phantom merge will not go away?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I only recently started using git to manage my product, and I am working in the same master repository from two places: IntelliJ IDEA on my PC, and in the shell on a unix server.
Somewhere along the way, I got something out of synch, and whenever I push a commit from one side, and pull it from the other side, the *pull* complains that it needs to do a **merge**.
So EVERY commit is followed by a merge (in which the merge only includes the contents of the just-added commit).
I have pulled the entire source tree from both sides, and every file is **bit-for-bit identical**.
There are no conflicts.

What am I doing wrong?
Do I need to change the default behavior from "merge" to "rebase"?  How?

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING**: this will destroy any work that you have committed locally and any work that has not been committed yet!

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master # assuming "master" is the name of your default branch
```

Git doesn't care about your files being equal, Git cares about *commits*. And from your description, I'm pretty certain that you have a commit locally that does not exist on the remote (or maybe you have rebased locally, amended a commit, or somebody else has rebased and force-pushed).

Any time histories (the "list" of commits) have diverged, Git *must* do a merge to bring those histories together. Merging creates a new commit, so the next time you merge (pull = fetch + merge), Git needs to merge again.